# Page expiry notification not sending emails - MOSS2007 / WSS3.0

Tags: alert, publishing-page

Just looking for some ideas around how to solve this particular problem.

Case:
My Intranet pages (publishing pages with workflow) are flagged with an expiry date and I am using the notify page contact option to send out a reminder email 7 days prior to the page expiring. This was being used as a strategy to keep the content on the intranet fresh and relevant and was working fine. Now, the email notifications are not being sent to the page contact. All other notifications on the site are working as expected.

- Publishing template pages
- MOSS2007 SP2 and WSS3.0, SP2, v12.0.0.6421
- 2003 Server SP2

**Was alerttemplates.xml modified?**
No

**Is there a timer job definition for sending email reminders?**
Yes

- Immediate Alerts - Intranet - Minutes
- Scheduled Page Review  - Intranet - Daily
- Scheduled Page Unpublish - Intranet - Minutes

**What is the Timer job Status?**

- Immediate Alerts - SERVER1 - Succeeded - 100% - (date: time)
- Scheduled Page Review - SERVER1 - Succeeded - 100% - (date: time)
- Scheduled Page Unpublish - SERVER1 - Succeeded - 100% - (date: time)

**Are alerts enabled?** 
yes, as other alerts and notifications etc are working as expected...

**Does exchange server allow sending of emails from the farm?**
yes, as normal alerts and "send to" functionality are working as expected...

**Object Cache flush**
No change

**Still to try:**
Clear config cache. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939308

Any other suggestions on how I might troubleshoot this and get these email notifications working again?

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1):

After many months of trying to find a resolution, a simple SP2 to SP3 upgrade has resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple more debugging steps...

Have you tried logging an item to the history list just before sending the email and then logging another after the email is sent? This is a good way to confirm that Send an Email activity is actually executing and things aren't hanging up somewhere before that.

Also, try logging an item to the history list that contains the email or user id of the person to whom the workflow should be sending the email (it should utilize the exact same lookup the Send an Email activity uses to populate the To: field). Dong this will confirm that the To address is populating correctly.